# swift can't call function after clicking button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have made a container view with a image view and a button inside for some reason when running the app in simulator i can't click button and call the function taking me to the next screen , i have encountered this kind of problem before and it was as simple as changing the button to a lazy var though that hasn't work on this occasion?

```
lazy var nameLabelButton = UIButton()




func setupNavBarWithUser() {

    guard let displayName = user?.DisplayName else { return }

    let titleView = UIView()
    titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
       titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleView.addSubview(containerView)

    let profileImageView = UIImageView()
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    if let profileImageUrl = user?.profileImageURL {
        profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString:profileImageUrl)
    }

    containerView.addSubview(profileImageView)

    //ios 9 constraint anchors
    //need x,y,width,height anchors
    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true


    containerView.addSubview(nameLabelButton)
    nameLabelButton.setTitle("\(displayName)", for: .normal)
    nameLabelButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    nameLabelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //need x,y,width,height anchors
    nameLabelButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    nameLabelButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabelButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabelButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    nameLabelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openUsersProfileController), for: .touchUpInside)



    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

}


func openUsersProfileController(){
    print("asdasdadsad")

    let openUsersProfileController = UserProfileController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    openUsersProfileController.user = self.user
    navigationController?.pushViewController(openUsersProfileController, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: You haven't provided any constraints to size your `containerView`, so it will be `0` wide by `0` high, making it impossible to interact with its subviews, ie the button.

Comment: vacawama sorry i just left out the constraints code and only put code i thought related to the question

Comment: Go ahead and edit your question adding the constraints back in.  They are important.

Comment: vacawama i have added all the constraints code

Comment: If you're using Swift 4 (Xcode 9.2), you'll need `@objc` before your `func openUsersProfileController`.

Answer (score 0):

well, code looks fine you just need to add `@objc`

```
@objc func openUsersProfileController(){
        print("asdasdadsad")

        let openUsersProfileController = UserProfileController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        openUsersProfileController.user = self.user
        navigationController?.pushViewController(openUsersProfileController, animated: true)

    }
```

**Reason**:

From `Swift 4`, we manually need to add `@objc`  before function.

Comment: thanks though it is still not working when i click the nameLabelButton which is located inside the container view